# MySQL How can I select the time difference between two log entries over a set?

Tags: mysql, data-analysis

I have a large set of log entries that I need to do an analysis on. What I want to do is select the time difference between the start and the complete entry, for each set of logs. How would I go about doing this?

```
Sample Log Set:

ExecuteTime, Entry, TrackKey
7.2408730984, Start update, 487996b0608b0006bfbe5501217c76bde879b728
9.9038851261, Complete update, 487996b0608b0006bfbe5501217c76bde879b728
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume start time is minimum and end time is maximum. If it isnt like that, this query will wrong

```
select TrackKey, (MAX(ExecuteTime) - MIN(ExecuteTime)) as time_difference
FROM table
WHERE Entry IN('Start update', 'Complete update')
GROUP BY TrackKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested :

```
SELECT * FROM Table AS t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(Sample) AS Min, MAX(Sample) AS Max FROM Table) AS t2 ON t1.TrackKey = t2.TrackKey
```

Updated :

```
SELECT
    (t3.End - t2.Start) AS Total
FROM Table AS t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            Sample AS Start
        FROM
            Table
        WHERE
            Entry = "Start update"
    ) AS t2 ON t1.TrackKey = t2.TrackKey
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            Sample AS End
        FROM
            Table
        WHERE
            Entry = "Complete update"
    ) AS t3 ON t1.TrackKey = t3.TrackKey
```